# Splidejs - Thumbnail Carousel - Scroll thumbnails without changing the main content?

Tags: javascript, splidejs

Im using [Splidejs slider](https://splidejs.com/) and the [Thumbnail Carousel option](https://splidejs.com/tutorials/thumbnail-carousel/). Is it possible to scroll the "thumbnails" (id="splide02" in the example) without changing the main image (id="splide01" in the example)?

I only want the main image to change when you click on a thumbnail. This way you can scroll through all the thumbnails and when click on the one that you want.

Try my example by [opening my product gallery and setting the mobile mode](https://mantaspersonalizadas.com/manta-polar-personalizada). You will see that scrolling the thumbnails will change the main image as well. I want to avoid this.